# How to Add a Custom Script to Customize.php

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script, theme-customizer

I am having a rather difficult time adding a script to the 3.4 Theme Customizer (i.e., customize.php).  If I want, I can deregister jquery and add it from googleapi as follows:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

That works just fine.  However, if I want to add jquery-color or some other script I just can't get it to work.  For  instance, this doesn't work:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-color' );
```

This also does not work:

```
wp_register_script( 'bpjquerycolor', 'http://localhost/bp2/wp-content/themes/buildpress/admin/scripts/bpjquerycolor.js');

wp_enqueue_script( 'bpjquerycolor' );
```

In terms of add_action, none of the following work:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'add_admin_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_scripts' );
add_action( 'init', 'add_admin_scripts' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_admin_scripts' );
```

I have also tried the following with no success:

```
global $wp_customize;
if ( isset( $wp_customize ) ) {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-color' );
}
```

In short, I've tried every combination that I can think of with no success.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I add this to the theme customizer?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 9):

It appears that 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts' also works and may be the intended function.

```
function theme_customize_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('customize-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/customize.css');
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_customize_style' );
```

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I figured it out. Instead of "init" or "wp_enqueue_scripts", etc. I had to use "customize_controls_print_footer_scripts" as such:

```
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', 'bp_admin_scripts' );
```

If you want the script in the header then you use:  "customize_controls_print_scripts"

And if you want to enqueue a style you use "customize_controls_print_styles"

I found this out by looking at the code for customize.php and noting the add_action codes used there on lines  30 - 32 (as of version 3.4.1)