# Sorting widget control

Tags: jquery, widgets, theme-customizer

[image]

Please guys, how can one use jquery sortable in the customizer area to sort hierarchy of an image widget and have it reflect on the actual page.

Like the way reordering of this widget stack reflects on the front end after ajax reload. The widget there is the "Dube DPM widget".

Comment: @WebElaine this is my first plugin for an image column widget with sortable order. I have have written the jquery code for sorting the images but I don't know how to communicate it to WordPress.

Comment: This related answer may help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63968/how-to-add-a-custom-script-to-customize-php

Comment: @WebElaine thanks, I have already enqueued the script

Answer (score 0):

I found that scripts for widget only work when included inline in the php file. Note: An external Js file might work for other dog elements outside the customizer area, but it is impossible to reference the dom elements in the customizer area.